# Get Authorization Bearer from Webbrowser to WebRequest

Tags: c#, winforms

I login with Webbrowser control on a website.

Webbrowser contains Authorization:

> Bearer Vw1Ta8yPpKV6N2bUOdyy....

in header.

Could I somehow get its information from control? I checked cookie with "GetCookieContainer()" but couldn't find any Authorization fields.

Comment: Technically the web browser doesn't have headers, its requests do. That then leads to the question: does the site store this information in local storage, session storage, or, and I'm assuming it's a SPA site, does it just store it in memory?

Comment: @john When I open this site on IE in debug mode. I see than Authorization stored in local storage, may be webbrowser use the same behavior, but I don't know how it is can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the next solution, make injection on javascript into a page.
After this you can to use _Bearer_Access_token  to make any request to you website.

```
    string _Bearer_Access_token = "";
    HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    HtmlElement scriptEl_ = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
    IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl_.DomElement;
    element.text = @"function GetBearer() 
                    {   


                        var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                        var aTag = document.createElement('a');
                        for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
                          aTag.innerHTML += localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) );
                        } 
                        parent.appendChild(aTag);

                    }";

    head.AppendChild(scriptEl_);
    webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("GetBearer");

    HtmlElement head2 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    HtmlElement scriptEl2_ = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    if (scriptEl2_.InnerText.IndexOf('{') > 0)
    {
        string LocalVariables_ = scriptEl2_.InnerText.Substring(scriptEl2_.InnerText.IndexOf('{'));
        LocalVariables_ = LocalVariables_.Replace("}{", "}@@@BTWOBJ@@@{");
        string[] ObjectArr_ = LocalVariables_.Split(new string[] { "@@@BTWOBJ@@@" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i_ = 0; i_ < ObjectArr_.Length; i_++)
        {
            JToken token_ = JObject.Parse(ObjectArr_[i_]);
            token_ = token_.SelectToken("access_token");
            if (token_ != null)
            {
                _Bearer_Access_token = token_.Value<string>();
                if (_Bearer_Access_token.Length > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```